# antdesign slider second label not shown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, antd

Using slider of antdesign (https://ant.design/components/slider) for my react project,

In slider show point with title in bottom successfully but on top not be able to show second title of points
code::

```
const marks ={
1 : 1.01¥
4 : 4.54¥
7: 7.98¥
}
```

and render();

```
<Slider 
     min={slider.min} 
     max={slider.max} 
     marks={marks} 
     step={slider.step} 
     included={false} 
     defaultValue={priceOfBestTrade} 
     onChange={this.onChange} 
     value={inputValue || priceOfBestTrade} 
 />
```

i have this output:::
[image]

**Actually i need two title first on top and second in bottom**

like this::
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
const marks ={
1 : 1.01¥
4 : 4.54¥
7:
 {
    label: <strong> 7.98¥<br />Price of Maximum value</strong>,
  },
}
```

Is this what you are looking for? Unable to figure out what exactly you are looking for, from your top and bottom wordings